# C# overload resolution and generics

Tags: c#, overloading, overload-resolution

I have the following methods

```
public static EnumerableAssertions<T> AssertThat<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Enumerable!");
    return new EnumerableAssertions<T>(collection);
}

public static ObjectAssertions<T> AssertThat<T>(T value) where T : class
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Generic fallback!");
    return new ObjectAssertions<T>(value);
}
```

But why does the following call resolve to the generic fallback?

```
List<object> list = null;
AssertThat(list);
```

From my understanding the overload for `IEnumerable<T>` should be more specific than the generic `T : class` but C# seems to see that differently. If I add an overload for the **exact** type `List<T>` it works just fine, but of course I don't want to add specific overloads for every type inheriting `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Why would you want to use a `List<object>` anyway?

Comment: @Deleted make it a List<string> if you like that better and the problem won't change. It's an example.

Comment: As an aside, which overload would you have wanted it to select if you provided a `string`? Bearing in mind that that type *happens* to be `IEnumerable<char>` but that's not the most common way of thinking about it.

Comment: _Apples and oranges_.  `AssertThat<T>(T value)` contains the explicit constraint `where T : class` whilst `AssertThat<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)`  has **no** explicit constraints at all.  `AssertThat(list);` is most likely resolving to the generic one because `List<>` is an reference type and is more in line with `where T : class` than an unrestricted `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example. And @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, `string` is not covered by this. In my logic I would have expected `string` to use the `IEnumerable<char>` overload, because that is (only considering the two overloads above) the most specific. If I want to have a specific overload for `string` I would need to add an explicit overload for the (exact) type `string`

Comment: @Deleted I know these are apples and oranges, but even the overload `EnumerableAssertions<T> AssertThat<TCollection, T>(TCollection value) where TCollection : IEnumerable<T>` with an explicit constraint won't be favored by C# over the generic fallback

Comment: _"I know these are apples and oranges, but even the overload"_ - Irrelevant.  The problem is with your code not theirs.

Comment: @Ralf _”make it a List<string> if you like that better and the problem won't change”_ - a shame you didn’t suggest List<float> in your moment of sarcasm and you would have hilighted the issue with the OP’s code.

Comment: _["Editing a question so that the provided answers are invalid is not the right way for the original user to get assistance. If they have further questions, they should post a new question, not invalidate the help they've already been given."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351629/585968)_.  I have rolled back your question to the time prior to any answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OP:

> From my understanding the overload for IEnumerable should be more specific than the generic T : class but C# seems to see that differently

*Apples and oranges.*

This method:

```
public static ObjectAssertions<T> AssertThat<T>(T value) where T : class
```

...contains the explicit constraint:

```
where T : class
```

...whilst:

```
public static EnumerableAssertions<T> AssertThat<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

...has **no explicit constraints at all**.

OP:

> But why does the following call resolve to the generic fallback?

The code:

```
List<object> list = null;
AssertThat(list);
```

...is most likely resolving to the generic one (the one with the `where T : class`) because `List<>` is a reference type and is more in line with `where T : class` than an *unrestricted* `IEnumerable<T>.`